# Golang: "can't scan type" error

Tags: go

Suppose that I have a struct d of some type Data. In Golang, I can easily marshall it to a string it using:

```
marshalled := fmt.Sprintf("%v", d)
```

but if I try to unmarshall it like this:

```
fmt.Sscanf(marshalled, "%v", &d)
```

I get an error:

```
can't scan type: *Data
```

Question: How can I parse a string to my struct without writing a custom Lexer/Parser? I'd prefer not to use encoding/json too.

Comment: Why don't you want to use JSON?

Comment: For example, if my struct has an array field (like struct Data { Values [3]int }), and the json to unmarshall is {"Values" : [1, 2, 3, 4, /*more than the array's capacity*/]}, then json.Unmarshal will run successfully, silently discarding the extra values. I do not know how many more undocumented quirks like this are in the encoding/json package.

Comment: The %v format isn't defined the same for all types, nor is it unambiguous. You need a serialization format, not the pretty-print output from the fmt package. How about using gob?

Comment: @JimB I guess I was hoping for a default pretty-read symmetric to the pretty-print. As for gob, since I want my marshalled text to be human-readable, I still need to write a custom decoder. Nevertheless, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @user44168: I wouldn't consider that an "undocumented quirk" with json, that's pretty standard behavior for serialization protocols in general. You could enforce a schema of your own by unmarshaling into a generic intermediate structure and checking the fields before applying them to the final type. The only serialization protocol with a standard enforceable schema that is also human readable I know of is XML. You may be better off working around the well-known behavior of json. (You can also implement `fmt.Scanner`, but I have yet to try that myself, or seen it used)

Comment: @JimB I'll keep in mind your comments about unmarshalling into intermediate structures and about standard behaviour of protocols (I expected a little more from Go?). As for fmt.Scanner - I've found just [one](https://github.com/rogpeppe/rog-go/blob/master/loopback/parse.go) example of it's use. It's not particularly friendly.